# Is SSH setup specific to user-id?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, passwords, rsa

If I create a SSH key setup for a `abc` user, `abc` can login to a remote server without prompting password.

With the same `abc` SSH setup, can an other user `def` can also SSH to remote server without prompting password?

I mean every user should setup SSH key with remote server if they want to connect without password prompt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Each user should have their own SSH keys and the public keys connected to those users should be set in the `.ssh/authorized_keys` file of any common user that user needs access to.

Your question is about unclear, but I will attempt to expand on some things you are saying.

First, a user and a key are two different things. One user can have many keys or many users can share the same key. It all depends on what level of access you might be dealing with and what you expect others to gain by password-less access.

In general, sharing the same key with different users is not a great idea from a security standpoint. Let’s say you want to revoke access for one user… How would you do that? The only effective way of doing that would be to remove the key from the server… But then you have to create a new SSH key and  share it again with other users.

The best bet for general use is to give each user their own key.

But since keys and users are different things, you can always have a remote user be generic and just add/remove keys as needed.

For example, many coding setups allow multiple users to use a common `deploy` user that an admin (or someone in charge) adds/removes keys to on demand. Everyone who deploys code will do so via the `deploy` user and can do so since their public key is added to the `.ssh/authorized_keys` file on the `deploy` user’s account. And if the employee leaves the company or is. no longer connected to the project? Just remove their specific key and life goes on.

But in general, each user should have their own SSH keys and then the usage of those keys—via something like a common/generic user account on a server—is how access is managed.

Answer (score 0):

Not without effort to break SSH security.  Each user has there own private key in their own directory (in addition to the SSH host key stored in a different directory). In order for someone else to use your SSH private key they would need to be able to read it, and SSH does not generally run when the permissions on that key are to open.

Also note there is a difference between a password - which is associated with a user account on the SSH server and is considered weak security and a passphrase which is used to protect a private key stored in the client and associated with a user session, and which you probably are referring to.

There may, if-course, be unknown vulnerabilities lurking which could allow a user to somehow gain the private key by reading memory which is not adequately protected, but this is not something Joe Average can do.